# MP4 not copying into xcode project?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, video, ios6

Whenever I try to drag and drop an mp4 file from finder into my xcode project, it doesnt show up in the sidebar. Ive been doing the same thing for almost 2 years, and it worked every time until today. It pops up with the dialog box to add the mp4, but then when I click add, it doesnt show up and I cant play the video! Why is it doing this, and how can I fix this? Thank you!

Comment: reboot mac, try another mp4

Answer (score 1):

1. In Project Navigator, go to your project and select the right `target`.
2. Go to the `Build Phases` tab.
3. Select `Copy Bundle Sources`.
4. Scroll down to find a small `+` button and click on it.

[image]

5. Then click `Add Other`.

[image]

6. Select the `mp4` file you want and add it.

It adds it to the sources and you can also see it in your project navigator no top of the other files.

Comment: Hmm. I've always just changed the "add to targets" checkbox and I've never had to do that before. Tried it, and for some reason it worked. Although I did just update Xcode, so that might be a cause. Anyways, thank you for your help. I appreciate it!

Comment: Xcode can act weirdly sometimes, without clear reasons! I tried dragging and dropping and it did not work. Just to make sure, I clicked on search icon and Xcode crashed!